# Devstack installation error

Tags: python, bash, openstack

I've been trying to install Openstack/Devstack on ubuntu ringtails rairing machine,when i try ./stack.sh script i get an error also i set the enviroment varible force=yes to fix another issue,why do i keep getting this error?

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up tgt (1:1.0.17-1ubuntu3) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript tgt, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing tgt (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tgt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
+ exit_trap
+ local r=100
++ jobs -p
+ jobs=
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ kill_spinner
+ '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+ [[ 100 -ne 0 ]]
+ echo 'Error on exit'
Error on exit
+ ./tools/worlddump.py -d
usage: worlddump.py [-h] [-d DIR]
worlddump.py: error: argument -d/--dir: expected one argument
```

Comment: Are you the author of worlddump.py?

Comment: No i am not the authoer of worlddump.py

Comment: Make sure to checkout a stable build of devstack, like stable/icehouse. See if the problem occurs on that version.

Comment: It is also broken in the stable/icehouse, c.f. https://bugs.launchpad.net/devstack/+bug/1333321

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't have `LOGFILE` set in your `local.conf` e.g.: `LOGFILE=/opt/stack/logs/stack.sh.log`.

Comment: fikovnik i tired setting the logfile i still get the same error

Comment: That is very weird, because if you look into the script itself you will se that there is a line `./tools/worlddump.py -d $LOGDIR` and the logdir is created like `LOGDIR=$(dirname "$LOGFILE")`. This is a bug of devstack, but if you set up `LOGFILE` variable, it should work. If it does not, you will have to provide more details.

Comment: I added this exact line at the beginning of stack.sh (With the other variables) and it worked fine. Thanks! (I used Centos 6.4 Minimal)  `LOGFILE=/opt/stack/logs/stack.sh.log`